# wordpress count per day plugin - display number with thousends seperator

Tags: wordpress, separator

I want to display the number of visitors by using this code:

```
                <p> All visitors: 
                 <?php global $count_per_day;
                 if(method_exists($count_per_day,"show"))
                 echo $count_per_day->getUserAll( $return );?><br />
                </p>
```

Currently it shows the number without thousend seperator.
I`ve tried "number_format($number)", but it won't work.

Comment: Can you elaborate what won't work means? What is the output are you getting? Can you please update the code that you used but didn't work?

Comment: I don't know exactly in which part of the code I have to insert "number_format". I've tried                 echo number_format($count_per_day)->getUserAll( $return );?><br />

Comment: ... Ive tried also this code but the number is still without separator:                      echo $count_per_day->getUserAll( number_format($return, 2, ',', ' ' )); ?><br />

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
echo $count_per_day->getUserAll( $return );?><br />
```

With these three:

```
$count_before = $count_per_day->getUserAll( $return );
$count_after = number_format(intval($count_before), 0, null, ' ');
echo $count_after;?><br />
```

This will output 7000 as 7 000. If you want another separator, replace the third variable in the number_format()-function. For example `'.'` will output 7.000.

Comment: It doesn't work. Unfortunately the number appears not correct. It must be 1542099 and the new number is 15420990

Comment: this doesn't work: number_format($count_before, 0, null, ' ') ... but when I replace the variable $count_before with a real number it works?!

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work. The additional "0" at the end of the number is caused by the "echo" funktion. When I replace "echo $count_after;" with "echo A;" the following number is displayed:  1542099A